# Python3k ctypes printf

Tags: python, printf, ctypes

`printf` returns 1 instead of "Hello World!" which is the desired result.

I googled it and think its because of the changes in the way sequences are treated.

How do I modify the code to print "Hello World!"?

[www.mail-archive.com/python-3000@python.org/msg15119.html](http://www.mail-archive.com/python-3000@python.org/msg15119.html)

```
import ctypes

msvcrt=ctypes.cdll.msvcrt
string=b"Hello World!"
msvcrt.printf("%s", string)
```

Comment: seconded, what is the question? Is it "How do I print a string using msvcrt printf from python?"

Comment: yup, forgot to specify. sorry about that.

Comment: printf doesn't return the string, it returns the number of characters printed.

Comment: I guess `print("Hello World!")` is not what you want to hear? :)

Comment: yeah, if i wrap print() around msvcrt.printf("%s", string), the result would be 1. I want to acheive "Hello World!".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument needs to be a byte string as well:

```
msvcrt.printf(b"%s", string)
```

The return value of printf is the number of characters printed, which should be 12 in this case.

Edit:

If you want the string to be returned instead of printed, you can use `sprintf` instead. This is dangerous and NOT recommended.

```
s = ctypes.create_string_buffer(100)   #must be large enough!!
msvcrt.sprintf(s, b'%s', b'Hello World!')
val = s.value
```

I don't know why you'd want to do this though, since Python has its own string formatting. `sprintf` is a dangerous method since it is susceptible to buffer overflows.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, i tried that after u suggested it, i got the value 12 now instead of 1. print(msvcrt.printf(b"%s", string))

Comment: how would i get printf to return "Hello World!" instead of 12? is that the length?

Comment: Thanks, i was looking thru someones code and didnt understand. Whats stopping someone from using printf instead of sprintf?
Edit:I tried it out i got b''

Comment: They do different things: printf prints a string to standard output, and sprintf returns the string.

Comment: So if i run the script with printf in a cmd prompt the script would spit out the string to the terminal?